# My Android Hello World Application will not execute or display?

Tags: android

I have successfully installed the Eclipse, and Android SDK to my Mac.  However when I run the program using the code below.  It always gives me the error.  "Sorry! The application Hello, Harris(process com.example.helloandroid) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.

```
//package com.example.helloandroid;

import com.example.helloandroid.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Hello, Harris Family.");
        setContentView(tv);
    }
}
```

Comment: Open the DDMS perspective in eclipse and look for the pane titled "LogCat."  That will contain what's known as a "stack trace."  Please find that and post it we can see what's actually happening.  Please see http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip124.html for a brief example of a stack trace.

Comment: It looks like you were trying to follow the ["Hello, World"](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html) example from the developers site, but you've got some unusual changes. Is there a reason why you commented out the first line? Did you add the `import com.example.helloandroid.R;` line for a particular purpose?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you directly set the TextView as the ContentView. You should better use a layout instead.

Comment: That is how the ContentView is set in the "Hello, World" tutorial on the Android dev site (which it appears the OP was probably trying to follow): http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html#ui.

Comment: I see. But then you should really follow the example and not import packages that (probably) don't exists. (-> Your first commented line)

Answer (score 0):

Is your activity inserted in the application manifest? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have not set a layout view, you only have a textview with no parent.

First set up the parent layout for your text view with something like this:

```
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(ViewPlay.this);
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(ViewPlay.this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

Then add your text view with :

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("Greetings");
tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
tv.setTextSize(18);
ll.addView(tv);
```

Now add the view to the layout with:

```
this.setContentView(sv);
```

Adding content to the screen dynamically as above can be very thorny, so where possible use xml.